# JBoss 7 - Where does the war get exploded?

Tags: war, jboss7.x, exploded

I would like to know which location inside JBoss 7 does the deployed 'WAR' file get exploded to? In JBoss 4.3 it would ge exploded somewhere within the 'tmp' folder but I am not able to find where it is getting exploded to in JBoss 7. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not really exploded, but rather mounted as a virtual file system (vfs). You can find the files in tmp/vfs/deployment* and tmp/vfs/temp*

More information here: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VFS3UserGuide

Comment: Within my WAR, there is a folder called settings.xsl that sits under src/com/a/b/c/util. Previously, in JBoss 4, I used to access the path of this file as this.getClass().getResource("settings.xsl").getPath(). However, this doesn't seem to work in JBoss 7 as this.getclass.getresource.getpath is returning the wrong path. Could you please let me know if I should be using some different api for JBoss 7 to load files within the WAR?